# Microsoft Graph API beta endpoint gives 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am testing the Microsoft Graph beta endpoint that sends invitations to guest users to join the tenant. The endpoint I am using is :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/invitations
```

Body:

```
 {
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "abc@xyz.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myDomain"
 }
```

I am passing the bearer token in Authorization header that I got for the local admin user through the ADAL4J api. However, this call gives me a 401 Unauthorized error. Following is the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "91f8129e-70cc-467d-a45b-9309e55788d6",
      "date": "2017-02-10T08:46:09"
    }
  }
}
```

Any clue on how to get this request working? On Github I have gone through other discussions([eg](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/238)) where users are facing the same issue.

Comment: Have you checked the scope claim in the access token? You can use sites like jwt.io to check them. Also, your question title talks about the Azure AD Graph, but this is *the Microsoft Graph API*. Don't mix them up, they are different APIs with different capabilities.

Comment: @juunas I am able to get info from the access token using jwt.io but I am not sure what is the scope claim. Are you referring to permissions?
I have changed the title of the question.

Comment: I have given all the permissions in the app for Microsoft Graph API. I can see that in the token info too.

Comment: A common mistake is to request all delegated permission, and then call using a token acquired using client_credentials (application only) flow, or vice versa  It will be hard to tell without you providing a code snippet or the some more details on the token.  You should be able to paste the access token directly into http://jwt.calebb.net/ to see the token and its claims.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT by claims is this ("scp:Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared") what you mean?

Comment: I am using the token acquired through ADAL4J for the local admin account.

Comment: juunas above has a great comment - I wish I had seen it before.  The detail to verify is here ...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429059/ms-graph-guid-for-permission-user-invite-all/46447317#46447317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token sent was obtained with resource as "https://graph.windows.net". The expected resource/audience for Microsoft Graph API is "https://graph.microsoft.com". Update your application manifest to include Microsoft Graph as a resource and request the required permissions. Then request token with above mentioned resource/audience.

Comment: Also (along with Sriram's advice), make sure you are configuring your app to request the correct permissions.  Please review the create invitation documentation: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/invitation_post which describes the permissions that your app will require.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sriram Dhanasekaran-MSFT and Dan Kershaw this solution worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I am excatly in the same situation as @adarsh hegde. But I am targetting an azure B2C instead.
I can get the token for the windows graph (using resource "https://graph.windows.net"), and I am able to create users whithin my web app that is registered with the right permission.

What I did is to acquire token for graph.microsoft.com on the same time, but this token doesn't let me use invitations giving me the same error as you :
`{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "91f8129e-70cc-467d-a45b-9309e55788d6",
      "date": "2017-02-10T08:46:09"
    }
  }
}`

**UPDATE:**
So here are the steps that I've done so far:

1. ADB2C directroy
2. Web app with OpenID registered in there with required permissions to manage users in the AD following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)
3. When admin is logged in, the Web app in trusted mode is able to let him  manage users (create/add/etc...)
4. Now what I want to use is the InvitationManager part of the MS graph (graph.microosoft.com) to be able to send invitation mail. can I redeem the code received in the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications to get access token for the MS graph? knowing that I already do that but for AD graph (graph.windows.net)

Thanks for the help