# MS graph guid for permission User.Invite.All

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

What is the guid value for  User.Invite.All permission in ***graph.microsoft.com***

**User.Invite.All  guid = ?????**

**Graph Invitations Permissions Security Solution Below in Answers** …

---

*(the below list is now updated with the User.Invite.All guid)*

```
----------------------------------------------------- 
Microsoft Graph (API) 
 - resourceAppId 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 
-----------------------------------------------------

User.ReadWrite.All 
   -  741f803b-c850-494e-b5df-cde7c675a1ca

Directory.ReadWrite.All (+)
   -  19dbc75e-c2e2-444c-a770-ec69d8559fc7

User.Invite.All
   -  09850681-111b-4a89-9bed-3f2cae46d706


-----------------------------------------------------
Windows Azure Active Directory (API)
 - resourceAppId 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 
-----------------------------------------------------

Directory.Read.All  
 - Read directory data 
 - 5778995a-e1bf-45b8-affa-663a9f3f4d04 

Domain.ReadWrite.All (*)
 - Read and write domains 
 - abefe9df-d5a9-41c6-a60b-27b38eac3efb

Directory.ReadWrite.All (+)
 - Read and write directory data
 - 78c8a3c8-a07e-4b9e-af1b-b5ccab50a175 

Device.ReadWrite.All
 - Read and write devices
 - 1138cb37-bd11-4084-a2b7-9f71582aeddb 

Member.Read.Hidden
 - Read all hidden memberships
 -  9728c0c4-a06b-4e0e-8d1b-3d694e8ec207

Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy
 - Manage apps that this app creates or owns
 - 824c81eb-e3f8-4ee6-8f6d-de7f50d565b7

Application.ReadWrite.All
 - Read and write all applications
 - 1cda74f2-2616-4834-b122-5cb1b07f8a59

Domain.ReadWrite.All (*) 
 - Read and write domains
 - aaff0dfd-0295-48b6-a5cc-9f465bc87928 

(*) Note these have the same name and description - two seperate guids within AD
(+) Notice same scope name in two diferent resourceAppIDs (Graph vs. AD)
```

The above list may be very useful to someone as I was not able to find an include file or type def anywhere.  Which makes sense as you use the text name in scope calls.

Comment: Scopes are requested using a space delimited string. Where are you seeing a place to pass a `GUID`?

Comment: Guid is a desperation to get around security errors related to the Invite API.  I have an app that does 1000 updates deletes and adds in 500 Graph API’s and everything works perfectly, except the Invitations API . ControllerName=MSGraphInviteAPI ActionName=CreateInvite  Insufficient privileges.   I get the same error in beta and v1.0 This is an application, I am beginning to wonder if it only works in a user context or something not obvious.

Comment: I don't follow how a `guid` helps get around a permissions error. Which scopes did you specify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Invitation Manager Microsoft Graph Security Permissions – Critical Detail**

The invitations “service” is part of Graph not part of AD.

AD looks like it is part of Graph and Graph looks like it is part of AD but they have different security setup contexts and scopes that happen to have the exact same permission names in some of the scopes.

If you are setting up an application in Azure that needs access to the Invitations API then make sure you **add a specific reference to Graph** in addition to the AD API reference that is created for you when you first create an application registration.

[image: Graph Application Permissions Invitation Manager]

[image: Graph Users.Invite.All detail]

FYI: The Invitations looks like it is part of normal full v1.0 Graph and not beta only anymore.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/invitation
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/invitation_post
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations 
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/invitations